# How is “so” used in this sentence?

Tags: meaning, conjunctions, writing-style

I found this text in one of my reading. I wonder what the role of **so** in the text because I find it hard to translate into my language.

> Since I am a teacher of and consultant in engineering and management, the majority of my contacts are with people who are analytical. quantitative, verbal, logical. These are certainly exellent traits for any problem-solver. However, **so** is the ability to conceptualize freely, an activity that requires a somewhat broader thinking vocabulary. I am deeply concerned with attempting to better define this cocabulary and with helping people expand in this direction.

Is **so** still the conjunction or is it carried any other meaning? 


Where is the subject of the text (is it eliminated for speficif reason)?


is using **so** here familiar with academic writing? 


are there any other words carried the same funcion as this **so**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The **so** refers to the "excellent traits" of the previous sentence.  You could also say: "However, an excellent trait is the ability to conceptualize freely..."

Comment: I think substituting so with "an excellent trait" will change the meaning of the text. What do you think?

Comment: At best, it would have to be *Another excellent trait is...* to preserve the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> *These are exellent traits for any problem-solver.*
>   *However, **so is** the ability to ...*

Note the inversion of the auxiliary verb *is* in the second clause; it should normally follow the subject noun phrase *the ability to ...* The two sentences together form a *So*-Tag, where *so* means ***also*** and refers to the predicate of the preceding clause, as Jens has pointed out.

- *Billy **went to the ball game**, and **so did** Mary.* (with *Do*-Support)
- *Frank **is tired**, but **so is** Mary.*
- *These **are excellent**, but **so is** that.*

Comment: So are you saying that it acts pronominally here?

Comment: Not pro-nominally, but pro-verbally. It represents the predicate in this construction; and in some others -- notice the deletable _so_ in _Bill hit the bullseye, and John did (so) too._

Comment: But I would still say that if it is replacing something else that 'pronoun' is the best label for that. ('that' replaces 'it is replacing something else')

Comment: _Pro-form_ is the general technical term; pro-noun, pro-verb, etc.